# PHP gethostbyname() returns original ip

Tags: php, networking, dns

I'm attempting to make a reverse DNS function using the `gethostbyname()` function, but whenever I input an IP string, say, `'104.16.34.249'` (SO's IP), it returns that string as the result. What am I doing wrong?

Code (neither works):

```
$table['ip-host']=gethostbyname($args['args']);
$table['ip-host']=gethostbyaddr($args['args']);
```

Comment: Show the code. Can only guess at your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the gethostbyname() was designed to do. It returns the IP address if you enter the host name. And if you enter the IP address it will return IP address back to you. If you want to get the host name back then use gethostbyaddr().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php

Comment: If gethostbyaddr() gives you the sane result then check the machine in question to see if hostname (aka computer name) has been assigned to this host.

Answer (score 1):

It is [expected behaviour](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php). `gethostbyname()` takes in a domain and converts it to an IP address.

> Returns the IPv4 address of the Internet host specified by hostname.

You get a host (IP) by name (domain name).

Try:

```
<?php
    echo gethostbyname('www.example.com');
?>
```

You should get an IP of the server hosting www.example.com.